# Closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^{n-p}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{p+k}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

How to get a closed form for $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-p}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{p+k}\;?$$

I tried to write binominal in term of gamma function but I got no result. What is your suggestion to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of problems it is best to have the summation variable running in opposite directions; also note that you can remove the distracting upper bound on $k$ since terms for $k>n-p$ will be zero anyway due to the second binomial coefficient. So apply symmetry either in the first or the second binomial coefficient, giving respectively
$$
  \sum_{k\geq0}\binom{n}{n-k}\binom{n}{p+k}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
  \sum_{k\geq0}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n-p-k}.
$$
The first summation can be interpreted as the counting way to choose $n+p$ elements out of a set of$~2n$, with $n-k$ coming from the first half, and the remaining $p+k$ from the second half. The second summation can be interpreted as the counting way to choose $n-p$ elements out of a set of$~2n$, with $k$ coming from the first half, and the remaining $n-p-k$ from the second half. The results are the same, since
$$
  \binom{2n}{n+p} = \binom{2n}{n-p}
$$
by symmetry. This summation is a specialisation of the [Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_identity).

Comment: can you explain more please ?

Comment: @user130806 Not unless you explain first which part of the above is not clear to you, or what parts of the argument you find missing.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{n - p}{n \choose k}{n \choose p + k}:\ {\large ?}}$.

> $$
> \mbox{Note that}\quad{n \choose p + k}_{k\ >\ n - p} = 0\quad\mbox{such that}\quad
> \sum_{k = 0}^{n - p}{n \choose k}{n \choose p + k}
> =\sum_{k = 0}^{\color{#c00000}{\LARGE n}}{n \choose k}{n \choose p + k}
> $$

$$
\mbox{Hereafter, we'll use the identity}\quad
{m \choose s} =\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ a\ >\ 0}{\pars{1 + z}^{m} \over z^{s + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
$$

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
> \sum_{k = 0}^{n - p}{n \choose k}{n \choose p + k}}
> =\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}
> \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{p + k + 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{p + 1}}
> \sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{1 \over z}^{k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z^{p + 1}}
> \,\pars{1 + {1 \over z}}^{n}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{2n} \over z^{p + 1 + n}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\color{#66f}{\large{2n \choose n + p}}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-p}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{p+k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-p}\binom{n}{n-k}\binom{n}{p+k}$$

Using [Vandermonde's convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) follows:
$$=\binom{2n}{n+p}$$